# This loop only works on the first iteration

Tags: c++, loops

This program works perfect on the first iteration, but on any iteration after, the second cin is skipped ans the message displays. Also, in the second iteration, if the name is two parts, like first and last name, then only the first will display.

Any help?

```
double calcGrossPay (double payRate, double hours);
double nPay (double& fedTx, double& localTx, double& stateTx, double& ssTx, double& netPay, double fPay);
void displayAll (double fPay, double netPay, string name);

double fedTx = 14, stateTx = 6, localTx = 3.5, ssTx = 4.75;

int main()
{

    while (!cin.eof())
    {
          string name;

          cout <<"Please enter your working name: ";
          cin >> name;

          if (cin.eof())
             return 0;

          double payRate, hours;

          cout <<"Enter your pay rate and hours worked, respectively."<< endl;
          cin >> payRate >> hours;

          if (cin.eof())
             return 0;

          double fPay = calcGrossPay (payRate, hours);

          double netPay = 0;
          netPay = nPay (fedTx, localTx, stateTx, ssTx, netPay, fPay);
          displayAll (fPay, netPay, name);

           system("pause");
    }
}


double calcGrossPay (double payRate, double hours)
{
       double extraT, fPay;
       if (hours > 40)
       {
       extraT = (hours - 40) * (1.5 * payRate);
       fPay = extraT + (40 * payRate);
       }
       else
       fPay = payRate * hours;

       return fPay;
}

double nPay (double& fedTx, double& localTx, double& stateTx, double& ssTx, double& netPay, double fPay)
{
       double totalTx = fedTx + localTx + stateTx + ssTx;
       netPay = fPay * (1 - (totalTx / 100));
       return netPay;
}

void displayAll (double fPay, double netPay, string name)
{
    cout <<"Below is "<< name << "'s salary information" << endl;

     cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2) <<"\nYour calculated gross pay is $"
          << fPay << ", and your net pay is $" << netPay << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cin >>` operator reads data only upto the first whitespace character.

So, if your data-reading is `cin>> name; cin>>payRate; cin >> hours`, and if you enter `John Doe 12 34`, then "John" will be read as the name, and "doe" will be read as the payRate. At this moment the data-reading will fail, since `doe` cannot be transformed into any numeric value.

Also, at this point the `cin` stream will enter into an `error state` upon which it will **cease to read any further data**. All attempts to read will simply be skipped. Therefore the reading `cin>>hours` will be skipped, and all reading in the next loop iteration will be also skipped. And any other data-reading from `cin` that you have in your app.

But you always can (and should!) check if there were any errors. You can check `cin.good` or `cin.fail` error flags so you can detect if the stream has entered into error state. Search on google or StackOverflow for "cin error handling" and you will quickly find examples.

After you detect the error, you can **reset the stream** by `cin.clear()`. This does not remove any data from the stream - it just clears the error flags so that the stream starts reading the data again. Mind that the old data is NOT removed. If after failing on `cin >> payrate` due to `Doe` you'd reset the cin, then the next data read would be `doe` again.

The last part of your problem is reading the string "name" so that it can include whitespaces. As I said, `cin >>` reads only upto the first whitespace, so it is hardlly usable here.

Instead, switch to reading a whole line of text through `std::getline` function. It's used like this:

```
std::getline( cin, name )
```

It will read whole line of text as the name, including any spaces, tabs etc. It will end reading on \n, \r or \r\n characters, depending on your OS.

Comment: I love your explanation. The cin's should be lined up, but the first cin is being skipped beyond the second loop.

'          string name;
          
          cout <<"Please enter your working name: ";
          getline (cin,name);
          
          if (cin.eof())
             return 0;
          
          double payRate, hours;
    
          cout <<"\nEnter your pay rate and hours worked, respectively."<< endl;
          cin >> payRate >> hours;
          '
sorry bout it being jumbled

Comment: This is because mixing `>>` and `getline` has a one gotcha. The `>>` operator LEAVES the whitespaces, including any 'enter' (\r\n). After first loop iteration, after reading the payrate and hours, the \r\n are left. Then the `getline` from next iteration reads them as "empty line". Between switching from `>>` into `getline`, you have to purge all whitespaces that were left by for example `std::ignore`. Read on SO topics about getline, you'll find them surely. If not, ping me, I'll find you an example. I remember I've written a few myself.

Comment: You're a genius. I got it working and love the fact you made me work for the solution.

Comment: I'm really happy you liked it:)